# Indexing in magento does not work. what to do?

Tags: magento2

I change in magento 2 admin one category name and this is not changed on frontend.
My all settings in Index Management is set to: "UPDATE ON SAVE" but it is not updated.

What is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it in production mode? Try flushing the cache as well as the indexers, here is a query i use to clear everything in development through ssh:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache var/page_cache/ generated/* && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
```